# VBA Code optimize , the code running too slowly

Tags: excel, vba

I made a macro that take data from closed workbook but unfortunately the code runs too slowly for me.
Just when i start the macro it loading around 2 or 3 second. I will be very thankful if you help me to optimize the code :

Hire is my code:

```
Sub Button4_Click()

Dim SRC  As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set SRC = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\a1068434\Desktop\TEST\asdasd.CSV", True, True)
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Activate

  Dim R As Range
    Set R = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) 'last cell in Column A with data
    If Len(R.Value) > 0 Then Set R = R.Offset(1)
    R.Value = SRC.Worksheets("asdasd").Range("G14").Formula
SRC.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Not a lot of optimizing to do, tbh. Opening probably takes most of the time.

Comment: Well, since the code opens the file, reads a value, sets a value, and then closes **without saving any changes** or persisting any state anywhere, the optimized version would be `Private Sub Button4_Click()`, followed by `End Sub`.

Comment: I bet if you `F8` over the `Workbooks.Open()` command you will discover the system takes several seconds to load the file in memory, as oppsoed to the milliseconds it takes to set the values/formulas.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - `R` is in `ThisWorkbook`, on `Worksheets("Sheet1")`. So maybe the `ThisWorkbook.Activate` and implicit `ActiveWorkbook` could be optimized.

Comment: @BigBen ah, makes more sense, yes

Comment: ^ Perfect opportunity to propose Rubberduck inspection :-)

Comment: How can there be sheets and formulas in a csv file?

Comment: `=B1+C1,15,20` Open this in Excel

Comment: @Andreas `=B1+C1,15,20` Open this in Excel

Answer (score 3):

Since your working with csv and just pulling but one value out of it, why not parse the text?

```
Private Sub Button4_Click()
    On Error GoTo Wrapup
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Open "C:\Users\a1068434\Desktop\TEST\asdasd.CSV" For Input As #1

    'skip to line 14
    For i = 1 To 14
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
    Next i

    'read in the 7th column
    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
    result = LineItems(6)


    'Output
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Worksheets("asdasd").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    If Len(R.Value) > 0 Then Set R = R.Offset(1)
    R.Value = result

Wrapup:
    Close #1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a great idea (+1)! Just a quick note about the hard-coded file handle though: prefer using the `FreeFile` function to get a free file handle - `#1` may or may not be available.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will make Excel open/close a workbook faster, other than getting a faster hard drive and opening/closing smaller files.

There *are* a number of ways your code can be improved though, notably:

- Using explicit access modifiers. `Click` handlers have no reason to be [implicitly public](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitPublicMember)
- Code that toggles off `ScreenUpdating` should always toggle it back on *whether there's an error or not*
- Getting the `Len` of a `Variant` with an unknown subtype is dangerous: you never know if you're going to hit a `Variant/Error`, and `Len(CVErr(xlErrNA))` throws a *type mismatch* error and you don't want that. So, verify whether the value `IsError` first.
- You **never** (99.99999% accurate) need to `Activate` anything. Worksheets that exist in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time can (should) be [accessed by their *code name* identifier](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/SheetAccessedUsingString).

```
Private Sub Button4_Click()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Const path As String = "C:\Users\a1068434\Desktop\TEST\asdasd.CSV"

    Dim source As Workbook
    Set source = Application.Workbooks.Open(path, True, True)

    ActiveWindow.Visible = False '<~ why bother?

    Dim lastCellWithData As Range '<~ no need for comments when names are descriptive
    Set lastCellWithData = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

    If Not IsError(lastCellWithData.Value) Then
        Dim lastCellStringValue As String
        lastCellStringValue = lastCellWithData.Value
        If Len(lastCellStringValue) > 0 Then
            lastCellWithData.Offset(1).Value = source.Worksheets("asdasd").Range("G14").Formula '<~ do you really mean .Formula?
        End If
    End If
CleanExit:
    source.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
    Resume '<~ for step-through debugging; make this the next stmt to highlight the error statement
End Sub
```